# What is the purpose of std::chrono::duration::zero()

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

Why is there a static function that returns the zero representation of a std::chrono::duration type ?

Isn't:

```
std::chrono seconds s;
s = std::chrono::seconds(0);
```

exactly the same as:

```
std::chrono::seconds s;
s = std::chrono::seconds::zero()
```

?

---

And is there a generic chrono::duration::zero object/function, that has an implicit conversion into each duration type ? That may be useful in a non-template situation.

```
seconds s = durationZero;
minutes m = durationZero;
```

This way, changing the duration type/precision would not affect the "zero assignments".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is to give some flexibility to the implementation, in the case where the duration of `zero` is not represented by `Rep(0)`.

[std::chrono::duration<Rep,Period>::zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/zero)

> If the representation `rep` of the duration requires some other implementation to return a zero-length duration, `std::chrono::duration_values` can be specialized to return the desired value.

It won't be a problem if you use `std::chrono::seconds(0)` but if you use templates then `some_duration::zero()` would represent zero duration, but `some_duration(0)` might not.

Or if you want to figure out if some time elapsed, and you can't or don't want to make any assumptions about the `duration` type.

```
auto t1 = some_clock::now();

// so something

auto t2 = some_clock::now();
some_clock::duration d = t2 - t1; // where you don't want to make any assumtions about duration

if ( d == some_clock::duration::zero() ) {
  // no time elapsed according to some_clock
}
```

You might be always able cast `std::chrono::seconds(0)` to that other representation, but it is clearer to use `some_duration::zero()` if you want to get a zero duration if `some_duration` is based on a template argument.

I never encountered a use-case for that, and I currently also can't find a meaningful example. The only thing that comes to my mind is temperature related if you want to that `zero` is always 0°C, so for a °F and °K it would return different values for `zero`.

Comment: does that mean, that I should avoid treating `duration(0)` the same as `duration::zero() ` ?

Comment: @AF_cpp in most cases this won't be relevant. It would only be relevant, if you want to have zero duration and the duration representation is given by a template argument for which you don't know if `Rep(0)` really represents a zero duration.

Comment: The only real use case I encountered is a user-defined `rep` where default construction gives you a `nan` (or some unusable value), and for whatever reasons the `rep` author did not want to provide a conversion from `int` literals, so `duration{0}` was also not an option.  In hindsight, `zero()` doesn't really earn its weight.

Comment: @HowardHinnant that also came to my mind, or where `Rep` is a struct to circumvent data type limits if durations have to be really large. But then a constructor accepting `int` should still be possible. And also a `Rep` where another value integer value then `0` represents a zero duration does not make too much sense to me.